# how to write a query for scenario?

Tags: mysql

how to write a single query for my scenario? 
I have three where conditions ?

```
select * (select * ,'sony' as searchItem from dg_deal_product where name like '%sony%' or
select * , 'samsung' as searchItem from where dg_deal_product where name like '%samsung%' or
select * , 'wip' as searchItem from where dg_deal_product where name like '%wip%') order by column desc,column2 desc,column3;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing here, but perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT p.*
      ,CASE WHEN p.name LIKE '%sony%' THEN 'sony'
            WHEN p.name LIKE '%samsung%' THEN 'samsung'
            WHEN p.name LIKE '%wip%' THEN 'wip'
            ELSE NULL
       END AS searchItem
FROM dg_deal_product p
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 DESC, 3
```